# What is the value of this resistor? I can't make sense of the colour-coding

Tags: resistors, colour-coding, fusible-resistor

I want to repair this kettle that stopped working after havings its internals wet, if I understood. It's a "Russell Hobbs 21040-70".

There is a resistor burnt. I can see the colors, but I'm not able to interpret them as I find they make no sense in any direction. They are black, gold, black, orange, orange. It's the R10 on the board, the label is visible once I desoldered it. I can't measure it of course.

From what I've read, orange or black mean nothing as a tolerance, and gold nothing as a value. What does it mean?

Also, I fear that the resistor may not be the only broken bit. If you have any advice on what to test, I'm eager to read them.

Here are a few photos:

[image: close-up of the resistor]

[image: front side]

[image: back side]

Edit : as many told me, the resistor is likely not the primary cause of the problem and it blows again when I change it. If anyone has an idea what to test...

Comment: (Also if there's ever a poll about the most stupidly over-engineered thing in the history of engineering, TH-resistor color codes gets my vote... Whatever you do, don't print it with digits!)

Comment: My best guess for the value is 33.0Ohm (orange = 3, black = 0, gold = 0.1x so 330*0.1=33). I'm unaware of what black as the tolerance values could mean though. As for other broken bits, I would be quite certain that other parts are broken as well. The resistor burning out is likely a result of another component sinking or sourcing too much current through it. That resistor may have been the lightning rod and protected other passives, but its a good bet that there is an IC or internal component connected to the resistor that is dead too.

Comment: @Lundin are you sure about the value?

Comment: Oh right these aren't read like SMD resistors where 330 = 33R. So it would be 330 x 0.1 = 33R

Comment: Or is the final black line temperature coefficient? Come on, someone find me the person who invented this **** system...

Comment: I'd also say 33 ohms 1%, with the extra black band indicating a special resistor. It likely means a safety fusible resistor based on it being on live mains input. But resistors don't burn without a reason, it blew up because it was a fuse for a problem elsewhere. A new resistor will likely burn up too unless the actual fault is fixed.

Comment: @Justme Some online guides claim the black line is 250ppm/K temperature coefficient. Some other online guides contract it and say it means "unknown". Other online guides say it means 1%. Basically this color coding system is so incredibly dumb so that literally nobody knows what it means, not even seasoned engineers nor resistor manufacturers. I mean we have some 10+ people reading this question where at least 5 are very experienced EE.

Comment: In a way, I feel less dumb now that I see that you're not sure either. I will test a new 33ohm resistor even if if fries right away, and let you know the result.

Comment: Ok, I can't really approve an answer, but admitting it was indeed 33 ohm, you were all right predicting that the resistor would burn again ; I soldered a 47 ohm resistor (all I had laying around) and sure enough, when I plugged the kettle back it went to smoke with a pop and all my coworkers were interrupted in their work until I turned back on the mains breaker :)

Answer (score 6):

I strongly believe that the resistor is a fusible one and meant to be an inrush limiter as well as a cheap & slow fuse, judging from its location. Typical values do not reach to hundreds of Ω, so it can't be 330.

I'm 99.9% sure it's 33 Ω (3 - 3 - 0 - x0.1 - ?). Black band might indicate something else which I have no idea about, so I left it "?".

Comment: They wrap a black band around the shoulder of the resistor to express their condolences with whoever tries to interpret the color code.

Comment: This is the right answer. [The black band almost certainly indicates a wirewound resistor](https://www.queenmao.com.tw/resistor_color_code.htm) and its purpose is fusing and inrush limiting. Replacing the resistor will likely not fix the underlying problem (in the same way that replacing a fuse will not fix a short circuit).